# What is the right way to add function handles recursive and see the right output after printing it?

Tags: matlab

This is what I tried:

```
f = @(x) 0;
for i = 1:n
    f = @(x) f(x) + x^i;
end
```

It seems to do the right thing, when I test it by putting in some values.

But when print `f` I got this output `f = @(x) f(x) + x^i`

EDIT: So how do I get the output I want to see, where all summands apear in the function handle, when I print `f`.

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? Your function is equivalent to `@(x) n*x^n` (non-recursive). Why recursion?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: And did you try the resulting function? I did a quick test (after replacing `^` by `.^`, and it seems to produce some higher order polynomial, as expected. You might be surprised by just a printing issue, but don't expect it to magically do symbolic math ...

Comment: The interesting thing here is that `info = functions(f); info.workspace{1}` just gives `f: @(x) f(x) + x^n` and `n: 5`. So it gives no clue what the function `f` is actually doing. It seems that `functions` _doesn't tell all the infomation that is carried by the function `f`_. In particular, it tells the values of variables used by the function, but not of a function handle used by the function if that function handle happens to be itself!

Comment: I expect an output for `n = 3` like: `f(x) = @(x) x + x^2 + x^3`

Comment: Then you need to change your original code anyway, as you have x^n at every stage of the loop - and `n` isn't changing.  But either way you won't get something pretty. Do you want something to print out nice, something to calculate the right answer, or both?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Eddit the Post. When I testing it for `n = 3` and `f(1)`, `f(2)`, `f(3)` I got the expected results. So, by now I am pretty sure, that it calulate the right answer. But when I building some more complex function handles, I wanna be sure, how the function looks like. So I'm searching, for a way to see the right output.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Everything is there, you just need to keep calling `functions` on any workspace field that is a function handle until you reach the bottom.

Comment: @horchler Oh, it totally makes sense now! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the symbolic functions (`symfun`) to do what you want:

```
% create symbolic variable
syms x

% define order of polynom
n = 3;

% create polynom
fs(x) = 0*x;
for i = 1:n
    fs(x) = fs(x) + x.^i;
end

% convert symbolic function to function handle
f = matlabFunction(fs)
```

Results in:

```
f = 
    @(x)x+x.^2+x.^3
```

**Edit:** Here is an approach **without** using the Symbolic Math toolbox:

```
% define order of polynom
n = 3;

% create polynom as string
fstring = '0';
for i = 1:n
    fstring = [fstring, '+x.^',num2str(i)];
end

f = str2func(['@(x)',fstring]);
```

Results in:

```
f = 
    @(x)0+x.^1+x.^2+x.^3
```

Comment: So there is no way by just using funtion handles?

Comment: No, because the `function handle` is just a _handle_ and not the function itself. Executing
`f = @(x) 0;
f = @(x) f(x) + x^1;
f = @(x) f(x) + x^2;`
will give you back the last line. This is exactly what you tell Matlab to do. It creates a function handle to a function handle plus some additional function. **Edit:** You _could_ only use only function handles by putting them in an array of function handles and reference each of them to the previous entry. But this will not generate you a nice output and is not the nice way of doing it. Just mentioned to give a 100%-answer to your question ;-)

Comment: @Matt: There may be a way to do this using the workspace field of the [`functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function, but it would probably be rather tedious to work up the hierarchy and pul in the values of any variables. The symbolic approach is probably most straightforward here.

Comment: @horchler This workspace is just a place where variables of the function (here: `i`) get temporarily stored. In the OP's example during the for-loop, the value of `info = functions(f); info.workspace{1}.i` gets changed in each iteration. This will still lead to the problem, that one has to actually save the function handle of each iteration somewhere. Otherwise the value is just being overwritten.

Comment: @Matt: No, it's not overwritten. This is how closures work in Matlab. You can walk up the hierarchy as I mentioned an see the value of `f` and `i` at each step. Try something like: `info = functions(f);` `info2 = functions(info.workspace{1}.f);` `info2.workspace{1}.i` Tedious, as I said, but possible.

Comment: @horchler You are right! I never thought that each of the function handles itself gets fully stored in the function's workspace. Therefore I did not try to access the function handle in the workspace of the old function handle. Of course it is tedious but a really nice remark to use these workspaces.

Comment: It has to be mentioned that this solution has to be modified for matrices. I think that replacing num2str to mat2str would do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a for loop, use `sum`,

```
f =@(x,n) sum(x.^(1:n));
```

Edit:

I misread OP's post and thought he wanted `sum(x^i)`. I new function that recreates his behavior and is valid to an arbitrary number of dimensions in `x` is

```
g = @(x,n) sum(reshape(repmat(x(:), 1, n).^repmat(n, numel(x), n), horzcat(size(x), n)), length(size(x)) + 1);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the same result as the OP function

Comment: But it produces the same results.

Comment: It now produces the same result as the OP.